# How to bypass the System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalPropertyEntry.ValidateNotDetachedAndInModel(String method) validation of Entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ninject.web.mvc, odac

I'm using a customized method for tracking individual modified properties of an n-tier disconnected entity class. I extracted it from

> Programming Entity Framework: DbContext by Julia Lerman and Rowan
>   Miller (O’Reilly). Copyright 2012 Julia Lerman and Rowan Miller,
>   978-1-449-31296-1.

The code is:

```
public void ApplyChanges<TEntity>(TEntity root) where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState {
        // bind the entity back into the context
        dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(root);
        // throw exception if entity does not implement IObjectWithState
        CheckForEntitiesWithoutStateInterface(dbContext);

        foreach (var entry in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<IObjectWithState>()) {
            IObjectWithState stateInfo = entry.Entity;
            if (stateInfo.State == RecordState.Modified) {
                // revert the Modified state of the entity
                entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                foreach (var property in stateInfo.ModifiedProperties) {
                    // mark only the desired fields as modified
                    entry.Property(property).IsModified = true;
                }
            } else {
                entry.State = ConvertState(stateInfo.State);
            }
        }
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The purpose of this method is to let the EF know only a predefined set of entity fields are ready for update in the next call of SaveChanges(). This is needed in order to workaround the entity works in ASP.NET MVC 3 as follows:

- on initial page load: the Get action of the controller is loading the
  entity object and passing it as a parameter to the view.
- The View generate controls for editing 2 of the fields of the entity,
  and holds the ID of the record in a hidden field.
- When hitting [save] and posting the entity back to the controller all
  of the fields excepting the 3 preserved in the view comes with a null
  value. This is the default behavior of the MVC binding manager.

If i save the changes back to the database the update query will of course overwrite the non mapped fields with a sentence as follows:

```
UPDATE non_mapped_field_1 = NULL, ..., mapped_field_1 = 'mapped_value_1', mapped_field_2 = 'mapped_value_2', ... non_mapped_field_n = NULL WHERE ID = mapped_field_3
```

This is the reason i'm trying to track the fields individually and update only those fields i'm interested in. before calling the custom method with ApplyChanges() i'm adding the list of fields i want to be included in the update to the IObjectWithState.ModifiedProperties list, in order to get a SQL statement as follows:

```
UPDATE mapped_field_1 = 'mapped_value_1', mapped_field_2 = 'mapped_value_2' WHERE id = mapped_value_3
```

The problem is, when marking one of the fields as modified in ApplyChanges, i.e.:

```
entry.Property(property).IsModified = true;
```

the system is throwing the following **exception**:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Member 'IsModified' cannot be called for property 'NotifyCEDeadline' on entity of type 'User' because the property is not part of the Entity Data Model.

at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalPropertyEntry.ValidateNotDetachedAndInModel(String method)

at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalPropertyEntry.set_IsModified(Boolean value)

at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbPropertyEntry.set_IsModified(Boolean value)

...
```

So the question is. There's a way to bypass this EF validation or let the context know of the existance of this system property (IsModified) that i'm trying to change?

Summary of the architeture:

- EF Code first (annotation + Fluent API)
- Oracle .NET EF Data provider (ODAC)
- Context is injected to a cutom business context with nInject.MVC => this is the reason i customized the ApplyChanges() method from

  using (var context = new BreakAwayContext()){ 
      context.Set().Add(root);

  to a simple call to the already initialized dbcontext

  dbContext.Set().Add(root);
- Oracle Database is created manually i.e. without the help of EF, so no EF metadata tables are used.

Thanks,
Ivan.

Comment: do you have resolution for this? I'm facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Very good description, however I can't find any information on why you need a transient property called "IsModified" in the object and/or why you need to tell EF about it being modified (EF won't be able to persist it anyway).

The value of the IsModified property should be set by the model binder if the property was incldued in the view anyway.

You could just add code in your ApplyChanges method to skip a property named "IsModified", or even better, filter only known properties using entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames, e.g.:

```
foreach (var property in stateInfo.ModifiedProperties) { 
    // mark only the desired fields as modified 
    if (entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames.Contains(property)) {
        entry.Property(property).IsModified = true; 
    }
}
```

**Update**: Ivan, very sorry I did not understand the problem better when you posted it several months ago and that I did not follow up after your added these clarifying comments. I think I understand better now. That said, I think the code snippet that I offered can be part of the solution. From looking at the exception you are getting again, I understand now that the problem that EF is detecting is that NotifyCEDDealine is not a persistent property (i.e. it is not mapped in the Code First model to a column in the database). IsModified can only be used against mapped properties, therefore you have two options: you change the code of the implementation of IObjectWithState in your entities so that non-mapped properties are not recorded in ModifiedProperties, or you use my code snippet to prevent calling IsModified with those.

By the way, an alternative to doing all this is to use the Controller.TryUpdateModel API to set only the modified properties in your entities.

Hope this helps (although I understand it is very late).

Comment: IsModified property: This is a internal property the EF uses mainly to know which entities needs to be included in the next SQL command. The EF's function DetectChanges() which is called when you call SaveChanges() automatically determine which of the entities bound to the current graph need and update, insert, delete, etc.

Comment: In the disconnected scenario where MVC works, there's no way for the post action of the controller to know of individual properties being changed after the initial retrieve from DB, which is made indeed with a different context in the get action. So the default pattern for us is just let EF know the ENTITY has changed and call SaveChanges(), generating a full update to the record.

Comment: This creates a problem because non mapped properties in the view will be set to NULL after the update we want in the database. The trick that i'm trying to replicate with this code is to unmark the entity as modified and then selectivally mark individual properties as modified in order the EF to generate an Update statement with only the modified properties, not the whole set.

Comment: This is supposed to work, because this code is authored by a recognized editor in the described book, but seems not to work in my project. If you follow the stack trace sequence, EF is validating if the set accesor of IsModified is in the model :| I don't really know why EF is doing this, because i'm not used to map system properties in code-first but custom entities and fields. if you google the name of this function ValidateNotDetachedAndInModel() nothing except this post is in the search results.

Comment: For your clarification in the code you posted correlated with the exception i posted, property is "NotifyCEDeadline" (one of my custom fields/columns tracked in the view). IsModified is part of the EF's API. Regards, Ivan.

Comment: Thank you very much Diego. I'll try with this once I have a chance.